# get jQuery DataTables to update location hash with ServerSide ajax calls

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to make jquery datatable append the parameters it sends to the server, to the location hash?

For example

`/myapp`

would be become

`/myapp#draw=2&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=name...`

That way someone can just copy the URL and share it with a friend and they will both see the same DataTables state.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jhyland87/DataTables-Keep-Conditions) should do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Keep Conditions](https://github.com/jhyland87/DataTables-Keep-Conditions) plugin for jQuery DataTables.

You need to include plugin JS file and enable it using `keepConditions: true` option as shown below.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   keepConditions: true
});
```

See [this example](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-save-and-restore-table-state-using-unique-url/) for code and demonstration.